# What is the proper way to create hyphen parameters in TCL that are Boolean or have values?

Tags: tcl

There are some answers for this issue and I have found a few things myself but they all differ. I want to find out about the most robust and proper way of doing something like this in the current version of TCL and its package library.

I need to create functions that can be called like this:

```
  go_somewhere_proc -walk
             -grocery {milk, oranges, tomato}
             -pharmacy {paracetamol, aspirin}
             -school
             -wear_sandals
```

1. The first parameter shown above can be walk, run or drive; not optional and no default value is assumed if it is absent.
2. Then is name of places to goto, depending on the parameter value itself this may or may not be followed by a list. The valid places are be grocery, pharmacy,  school and church. Atleast one must be specified.
3. The grocery option is followed by a list that cannot be empty. The names of items shall not be validated but must be less than 10. They can repeat.
4. The pharmacy option is followed by list that must contain atleast two items. The possible values are paracetamol, aspirin, lemsip, vitamin and protein in any order. The values in list must not repeat.
5. Finally the -wear_sandals is an optional parameter and is boolean.
6. It must be possible to specify the hyphen parameters in any order but the list corresponding to a hyphen parameter must follow it.

I have yet found this:

https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/parse_args

https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/argparse

https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/extending+the+notation+of+proc+args

Comment: The function is just an example. As long as I know how to write this type of hypothetical function, the question will be answered.

Comment: I'd recommend [cmdline](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/cmdline/cmdline.md) from tcllib. [Here](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/cmdline/cmdline.md#section4) is the example.

Comment: I second that, and have marked this as a Duplicate of a question that is extremely similar in what it is actually asking and what the answer will be. It's not an answer that's changed radically in the past decade or so. (There are different patterns that apply if you're parsing using the Tcl C API.)

Comment: Should I just look at cmdline package? parse_args? argsparse? or define the proc parameters as args and then treat it like a list and parse it myself? Please give me 1 way and will study it in depth. I am getting confused by the multitude of ways, that is all.

Comment: Can someone please tell me the difference between using cmdline package, args_parse package, parseargs package is just using custom solution while treating the input arguments as a list input using tcl args